# Bot Framework: How to Configure OAuth connection to use Added Skill in Virtual Assistant

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, botframework

I am running the `botskills connect` command to [add skills to a virtual assistant bot](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/addingprebuiltskills.md). Although the skills are successfully added, the following message appears.

```
Could not configure authentication connection automatically.
There was an error while executing the following command:
        az bot authsetting list -n virtualassistantbot-XXXXXX -g virtualassistantbot-XXXXXX${err}
You must configure one of the following connection types MANUALLY in the Azure Portal:
        Azure Active Directory v2
For more information on setting up the authentication configuration manually go to:
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/howto/assistant/linkedaccounts.md#authentication-configuration
```

After running the command, I am unable to even run the bot because

```
'You must configure at least one supported OAuth connection to use this skill: ToDo Skill.'
```

I tried following the steps in the given [link](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/howto/assistant/linkedaccounts.md#authentication-configuration) in the output but to no effect, but that is because they assume I am using the Linking Accounts sample project. But it is not clear to me how to apply this to the context of adding a skill to my VA, i.e. what are the exact steps I must take to set up an OAuth connection for the added skill to be used in my VA?

Comment: Have you tested that your oauth is correctly configured in the azure portal?

Comment: Can you please elaborate where I need to do configurations for oauth in Azure portal?

Comment: Helpful links: [link1](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/reference/skills/skillauthentication.md) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth)

Comment: looking into this now.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?